# PhoneStateListener callbacks not being called despite declaring locally

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an issue with getting the callbacks from PhoneStateListener in fragment.

Here is the setup:

```
class StatusBarFragment {

    private lateinit var telephonyManager: TelephonyManager

    val phoneStateListener: PhoneStateListener = object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onServiceStateChanged(serviceState: ServiceState) {
          Timber.d("Current cell state : ${serviceState.state}")
        }

        override fun onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength: SignalStrength) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                Timber.d("Current cell signal: ${signalStrength.level}")
            } else {
                Timber.d("Current cell signal:${signalStrength.gsmSignalStrength}")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE or PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS)
    }
}
```

The logs are not invoked (even once). What can be the issue?

Comment: What is `Timber`?

Comment: @TheWanderer it is popular logging library in Android

Comment: Just to make sure, try using normal Android logging methods (`Log.d()`).

Comment: did you add permission? Note that access to some telephony information is permission-protected.

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov yes, I've added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Then I do not see the reason why this listener might be wrong, can you put breakpoint into listener's body and check will this work (don't trust Timber )) )

Comment: Can you prove it then providing the working example?

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov I've put the breakpoints - it is not getting called

Comment: Well, your listener will only be called upon if "changes to the network service state (cellular)." OR "changes to the network signal strengths (cellular)." occur as per the official docs at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener
and
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager

So, make sure either the network service state changes or the signal strength changes during your testing.

Comment: Man I do not know what is wrong with your device, but I checked your code in the emulator it works fine for me, I see logs even if the value did not change
$phoneStateListener: Current cell signal: 2
$phoneStateListener: Current cell signal: 2